# C# Implement interface through delegate

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I want to create an `ObservableList<T>`, but as an `DynamicObject`, so I can map the elements as properties. That's why I have to inherit from `DynamicObject` instead of `ObservableList<T>`.

```
public class DataFieldList : DynamicObject, ICollection<DataField>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private ObservableList<DataField> _list;

    public DataFieldList()
    {
        _list = new ObservableList<DataField>();
    }

    public Object this[String name]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this[binder.Name];
        return result != null;
    }
}
```

Now I still need to implement the interfaces, so I can use the class like an `ObservableCollection`. I'd like to use my `_list` as delegate that implements these interfaces, but this seems to be impossible...

This feature is included in Delphi via the `implements` Keyword for properties:

```
property Collection: ICollection read _list implements ICollection;
```

I know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253366/how-to-delegate-interface-calls-to-a-member-that-implements-the-interface) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262315/implements-interface-using-member-as-implementor/6262684#6262684) questions basically are the same, but the solution of inheritance isn't possible for me, and also I can't really just expose the interfaces as properties. This would work out, even if a bit inconvenient to use, for `ICollection<T>`, but not for a property of `INotifyCollectionChanged`, because this defeats the purpose - WPF won't notice any changes if the interface isn't implemented by the object I bind to.

So is there any other way to get a class, that behaves like a `ObservableCollection<T>` but also allows me to access dynamic properties like a `DynamicObject`?

---

The use case is a grid that gets a collection of `DataFieldList` as source as well as a Collection of Column Names.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type dxg:GridControl}}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{TemplateBinding Rows}">
    <Setter Property="ColumnsSource" Value="{TemplateBinding Columns}">
    <Setter Property="ColumnGeneratorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Name}"/>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>  
</Style>
```

Here, the `Rows` property contains a DataSource that provides rows as `DataFieldList`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should get something like this

```
public class DataField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class PropertiesCollection
{
    public PropertiesCollection(IEnumerable<DataField> collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    private IEnumerable<DataField> _collection;

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomList : ObservableCollection<DataField>
{
    private PropertiesCollection _collection;

    public CustomList()
    {
        _collection = new PropertiesCollection(this);
    }

    public PropertiesCollection Properties
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Properties)));
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```

And binding will look something like this:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties[SomeProperty],Mode=OneWay}">            
    </TextBlock>
```

I.e i just use composition instead of inheritance.
Unfortunately, we have to be satisfied with only the composition( And you know very well that multiple inheritance is not supported in C#.

Comment: But this way, the binding won't try to use the dynamic properties... i really need an object that WPF can use to bind to and also receive the CollectionChanged from

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to see this in the xaml markup?

Comment: I rewrote my code. See if this solution is right for you.

Comment: so it comes down to implementing everything and passing it through... thx anyways. I'll accept this if no better answer is posted within the next few days

Comment: Any methods that change the collection, you can change and make sure that they are notified of changes to the collection. For example: 
     
  public void Add(DataField item)
        {
            _innerCollection.Add(item);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(item.Name));
        }

And then everything really works.

Comment: I propose to opt out of the Dynamic Object.

Binding will look something like this:

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties[SomeProperty],Mode=OneWay}">            
        </TextBlock>

Comment: So, I rewrote my code again. In this decision, of course there are negative: in markup instead "SomeProperty" you should write "Properties[SomeProperty]".

Comment: the problem is that the grid tries to bind the field on the column names, but since my column type `DataFieldList` isn't strongly typed (because the columns are only known at runtime) it hasn't got properties but must be accesed with ['ColumnName']